# Attachments to a video event

Tags: files

Let's assume that there is a video event platform. When a host creates an event they can attach some files to it. These files are stored permanently for all the participants even after the event ends.

There is another type of files which exists when the video event takes place. They are temporary and to be removed when the event finishes. It's like live chat of files during the event.

The question is does it makes sense to save files from the live chat and attach them to an event? Should it be made automatically or it's better asking the host to attach each separate file?

Comment: As fas as I understand we are not talking about live streams, right? If the viewer starts the video 2 minutes after the start of the event, they'll see the video beginning at 00:00 but maybe missing the final 2 minutes, because the video is deleted at that time. In cases of live streams the viewer would miss the first 2 minutes but can watch it until the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would depend entirely on what the event is. In most cases, making "in-event" attachments available after the event is *probably* OK, but I can imagine situations where a host wouldn't want this.

I would suggest a pre-event set of options for the host to pick between:

- Automatically make all "in-event" attachments available permanently after the event.
- Automatically delete all "in-event" attachments after the event.
- Let me decide what to do with "in-event" attachments after the event.

The last option would allow the host to review each attachment and decide whether to "publish" it or not.